# jq remove element from array by value

Tags: arrays, json, jq, array-difference

I'm using `jq` and trying to remove an element from an array based on it's value by can't figure out the syntax, it works with map but not del:

input = `[10,11,12]`

`echo $input | jq -r 'map(select(. == 10))'` returns `[10]`

`echo $input | jq -r 'del(select(. == 10))'` returns `[10,11,12]` not `[11,12]` as expected

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`del` is intended for deleting-by-path, not by-value:

```
 [10,11,12] | del(.[0]) #=> [11,12]
```

One way to achieve what you want is to use `select`:

```
 [10,11,12] | map(select(. != 10))
```

Another would be to use array subtraction:

```
 [10,11,12] - [10]
```

But that's maybe too easy.

Comment: I see, I think the 2nd option is what I was aiming for. Thank you.